# How to get a reference to a Table in a tab/worksheet that isn't the active one

Tags: c#, excel

I have some existing custom Excel workbooks/applications with code-behind C#, which work fine.  They do things like referencing Tables defined in the active worksheet, setting their datasources to IEnumerables, etc.

However, now I need to reference a Table which is not in the active sheet.  Basically, the active sheet has a button that triggers some C# code-behind, and I need to figure out how to get a reference to a Table on the fourth tab/worksheet in my workbook while inside the code-behind for the first tab/worksheet (the active one).

In my existing code (which works), I can do this on the active sheet:

```
this.Table1.DataSource = results;
this.Table1.RefreshDataRows();
```

... so the "Table1" reference is right there and I can access it easily.

However, trying to get a reference to a Table in the other sheet, I run into ComObject errors.  For example, I was hoping that this (or something like it) would work:

```
((Sheet4)Application.Worksheets[3]).Table2.DataSource = results;
((Sheet4)Application.Worksheets[3]).Table2.RefreshDataRows();
```

... but that throws the error: "Cannot convert type 'System.__ComObject' to ContractStatementClient.Sheet4'".  Writing those lines allows Visual Studio to find the Table (Table2) using IntelliSense, but at execution time it fails with the ComObject error I mentioned.  "Sheet4" is the name of the class that Visual Studio created for me when I made the new tab.

I can get references to Worksheets that seem to work by doing:

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[3]
```

... but I can't seem to figure out how to get from there to having a handle to a Table (or ListObject), that I can set the DataSource property on, as I've done in the past.

I tried this, but it throws a "NOINTERFACE" COM error during the cast:

```
Worksheet worksheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[3];
((Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject) (worksheet.ListObjects[1])).DataSource = results;
```

Am I missing something obvious?  I know next to nothing about COM, so it's tough for me to diagnose what's going on.  In the end, I just need to figure out how to set the datasource for the Table/ListObject in the other tab/worksheet (and presumably tell it to refresh itself).

Thanks!  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[3].Table2.DataSource` not working either?

Comment: In order to get Visual Studio to go along with that, I have to do something like: `((Sheet4) Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[3]).Table2.DataSource = results;`, but at runtime it throws `Cannot convert type 'System.__ComObject' to 'ContractStatementClient.Sheet4'`.

Comment: I should say that at this point, I've worked around the problem by creating a static container for all my worksheets at the workbook level, and having the worksheets add themselves to that container when they start up.  So I can directly access each worksheet through my container, and bypass all that COM business (which I don't grok).   I'm still curious if anyone has a more straightforward answer to getting ahold of these objects!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following approach, which worked quite well.

At the workbook level, I added a static array of type "WorksheetBase", and instantiated it in the "startup method for the Workbook, like this:

```
public static WorksheetBase[] StoredWorksheets;

private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    StoredWorksheets = new WorksheetBase[5];
}
```

Then, in each individual worksheet, I added this to the "startup" method:

```
private void Sheet1_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThisWorkbook.StoredWorksheets[0] = this;
}
```

Each worksheet knows which zero-based index it falls in, so this particular sheet uses index == 0, whereas the second sheet would use index == 1.

Now, when I want to access a specific member of another worksheet anywhere in my client, I reference the appropriate index, cast to the appropriate type for the sheet I want, and go to town:

```
((Sheet4)ThisWorkbook.StoredWorksheets[3]).Table2.DataSource = results;
((Sheet4)ThisWorkbook.StoredWorksheets[3]).Table2.RefreshDataRows();
```

I'm sure there is a more straightforward way to do this using the COM back-end, but darned if I could figure it out.  Hopefully this helps somebody else save some time!